# Allow user to opt in to MFA

Tags: keycloak

I have been able to leverage Keycloak's "Default Actions" section in "Authentication" to *force* new users to setup MFA via Google Authenticator.

[image]

However, I've only been able to make this *required* for all users or not even possible to turn on. I'm looking for a way to allow users to **opt in** to MFA via OTP if they would like during Sign Up.

Comment: User can configure OTP in the account console anytime. You will need to change/extend registration flow sokehow if you want to add optional OTP opt in.

Comment: So basically, you want to make it optional and ask the users nicely if they want to use it?

Comment: @Menelaos exactly

Answer (score 0):

There is no default option out of the box to implement this authentication flow.

You can create a custom authentication flow with a step asking the user to do the MFA.

This can be made using a javascript authenticator (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_script_providers) or a java service provider interface. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Authentication api, and specifically the one for extending the registration page/form.

See: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#modifying-extending-the-registration-form

I will give it a try tonight, and update my answer.